# How to set focus in HTML input box from PyQT QWebView?

Tags: python, html, pyqt, qwebview

I have a HTML page with two input boxes. Can I set the keyboard focus to these input boxes from python? Currently I am handling the keypressEvents from python. A code snippet is given below

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        input1 = self.page.mainFrame().findAllElements("#myinput1")
        input2 = self.page.mainFrame().findAllElements("#myinput2")
        key = event.Key()
        if key == ARROW_RIGHT:
            input1.setFocus()
        if key == ARROW_LEFT:
            input2.setFocus()
```

After pressing the RIGHT_ARROW, I have ensured that the element captured focus by using the below code

```
    print input1.hasFocus()
```

it returns TRUE. But when I try to enter some text, it doesn't show anything. Is that anything I have missed out ? I can enter the text if I click the mouse in the input box or I can change the focus using TAB key; but that is not exactly I want.

Any solution is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.textField('tf0', changeCommand='cmds.setFocus("tf1")' )
cmds.textField('tf1', changeCommand='cmds.setFocus("tf2")' )
cmds.textField('tf2', changeCommand='cmds.setFocus("tf0")' )
cmds.showWindow()
```

I am not sure but you can try this

Comment: what is this module maya used for ? I am getting error "No module named maya.cmds"